# How do I inject Javascript into web view in Ionic Android?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, webview, ionic-framework

I am trying to add a header bar in web view for my app. I am using the cordova [`inAppBrowser`](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git) plugin for this. To test it I added this code:

```
var win = window.open( URL, "_blank", 'location=yes' );
win.addEventListener( "loadstop", function() {
    win.executeScript({ code: "alert( 'hello' );" });
});
```

The URL opens but I do not get any alert in the web view.

**EDIT:**

So, after some debugging I figured out that the method `executeScript()`isn't defined. That is I get an error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. The same happens when I use `win.show()` and `win.addEventListener()`. Only `open()` and `close()` seem to work. Is there some problem with the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
var s=document.createElement('script');
s.src=alert( 'hello' );
s.type='text/javascript';
```